# Rails got error in .all method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi after update from rails 4.0.0 to 4.1.0 got this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

in view code:

```
<%= user_progress membership.progress %>
```

it comes from membership.rb

```
Lesson.all(:conditions => {:course_object_id => self.course_id}, :order => "lessons.sort ASC, lessons.start_date").each do | lesson |
  all_lessons[lesson.id.to_s] = lesson
  all_lesson_ids << lesson.id.to_s
end
```

whats wrong in this snipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the way you're constructing the query from:

```
Lesson.all(:conditions => {:course_object_id => self.course_id}, :order => "lessons.sort ASC, lessons.start_date")
```

to

```
Lesson.where(:course_object_id => self.course_id).order("lessons.sort ASC, lessons.start_date")
```

so it looks like this:

```
Lesson.where(:course_object_id => self.course_id).order("lessons.sort ASC, lessons.start_date").each do | lesson |
  all_lessons[lesson.id.to_s] = lesson
  all_lesson_ids << lesson.id.to_s
end
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Felix: Just to explain, the arguments you are passing belong to an old ActiveRecord query API, this was depricated and dropped a while ago, this is the new API as mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the documentation [`all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all) method doesn't accept any arguments. In your case you can use [`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) method.